# How to get lat/long of all adresses inside a polygon in google map?

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-api, google-earth

I have several polygon shapes inside a City in Germany. I need to generate Point data of houses inside those Polygons. It is very time consuming to add all the building Locations manually. I am wondering, if it is possible to extract the Point for all address somehow from Google maps as XML or kml Format.

For your Kind information, I do not have any Point data. I need to generate it somehow using Google map or Google earth from geocoded address. That is now the main challenge for me.

Comment: Rereading your post I think you are asking about getting address data out of Google Maps and I don't think you will be able to do that unless you have a source for the address data. You might try contacting the specific municipal government in Germany and see if you can get address points from them.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a mesh of, for example, 0.001 degrees on each side, and make a reverse geocoding for every point. The google geocoder service would answer with N possible addresses.

Each reverse geocoding request would have the following structure

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
         map.setZoom(11);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
           alert('No results found');
        }
    } else {
        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Of course, this won't be an exhaustive directory of all addresses, but it will get you a nice sample of addresses.

Btw, the geocoder has a request limit for each day, and it's also throttled on its requests per seconds capacity.

Answer (score 2):

here.com's API can, supposedly, give you up to 100 addresses within a circle.

This is how I create the URL for the API call

```
function makeURL ( point, radius) {
    return 'http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json'
        + '?app_id='+config.Here.App_Id
        + '&app_code='+config.Here.App_Code
        + '&mode=retrieveAddresses'
        + '&gen=7'
        + '&prox='+point.lat+'%2C'+point.lng+'%2C'+radius
        + '&maxresults='+config.Here.limit;
}
```

I'm using this to step over my polygon and try to get all the addresses.

I say supposedly, because I have noticed that there are addresses missed by this call, I haven't figure out why yet..., but seems to be better than grabbing one per point.

Comment: Is there a way though to stay within the confines of a set of polygon coordinates?